# Does os.path.sep affect the tarfile module?

Tags: python, windows, tarfile

Is the path separator employed inside a Python `tarfile.TarFile` object a '/' regardless of platform, or is it a backslash on Windows?

I basically never touch Windows, but I would kind of like the code I'm writing to be compatible with it, if it can be. Unfortunately I have no Windows host on which to test.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A quick test tells me that a (forward) slash is always used.

In fact, the tar format stores the full path of each file as a single string, using slashes (try looking at a hex dump), and python just reads that full path without any modification.  Likewise, at extraction time python hard-replaces slashes with the local separator (see `TarFile._extract_member`).

... which makes me think that there are surely some nonconformant implementations of tar for Windows that create tarfiles with backslashs as separators!?

Comment: thats wrong, on windwos, pythons `tarfile` uses backslashes.afaik you have to do sth like `tarinfo = tarfile.TarInfo(os.path.join(...).replace('\\', '/'))`